# Installing older version of symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new with symfony framework and I'm trying to install older version (4.1) with command
**composer create-project symfony/skeleton ./ "4.1.*"** but I'm getting an error **Unrecognized option "cookie_samesite" under "framework.session"**.
Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Ok, not sure if this is solution but I commented out lines 306-311 in ArrayNode.php

Comment: And? What happened?

Comment: error disappeared

Answer (score 2):

The command should be like :

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name "4.1.*"
```